# React native run-android stuck on reading file permissions

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I ran react native run-android , it compiles very well but it has been stuck on reading file permissions when trying to installDebug since, anybody know what I can do

```
 > Task :app:installDebug
[EmulatorConsole]: Failed to start Emulator console for 5554
09:17:15 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
09:17:16 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
09:17:16 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'emulator-5554 - 4.4.4' for app:debug
09:17:16 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
09:17:16 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
09:17:16 D/ddms: Reading file permision of C:\Users\JayK\Desktop\React\medlib\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
<============-> 99% EXECUTING [36m 3s]
> :app:installDebug
> IDLE
```

Comment: same issue for me ,

Comment: What emulator are you using...because I found a solution

Comment: What solution did you find? Please share!

Comment: What emulator are you using?